# FluentNHibernate mapping a join table with extra data

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a very simple database table that joins two other tables in a many2many relationship.

(pretty much joining users to questions - think bookmarking)

My NHibernate entity for this table looks like this:

```
public class UserToRequestSubscription
{
    public virtual int Id{get;set;}
    public vitual int UserId{get;set;}
    public virtual int RequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool AcceptedByRequester { get; set; }
}
```

What I'd like to do is add a new property:

```
    public virtual RequestForHelp Request { get; set; }
```

So far I can get this to work for selects. In my `UserToRequestSubscriptionMapping` I can simply do: `References(x => x.Request)`.

The problem I'm having is when trying to insert a new `UserToRequestSubscription` which throws: `Invalid index 6 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=6.`.

I've read up on this error and it vanishes when I remove the `RequestId` property however without this, the RequestId field in the DB is not populated when inserting a new subscription.

How do I go about doing this?

My aim here is to save doing extra calls to the DB for the `RequestForHelp` items.

**Here's the mapping class:**

```
public UserToRequestSubscriptionMapping()
{
      Id(x => x.Id);
      Map(x => x.UserId);
      Map(x => x.RequestId);
      Map(x => x.CreatedDate);
      Map(x => x.AcceptedByRequester);
      Map(x => x.IsActive);
      Map(x => x.DeactivatedDate);
      References(x => x.Request).Column("RequestId");
      Table("TheTable");
  }
```

Comment: What does the full mapping look like?

Comment: Thanks @HackedByChinese, I've added the mapping to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess the problem lies in that you reference RequestId twice according to your mapping. I think the `RequestId` property is superfluous once you add `Request`.

```
public class UserToRequestSubscription
{
    public virtual int Id{get;set;}
    public vitual User User{get;set;} // you'd probably also change this, too
    public virtual RequestForHelp Request { get; set; } // changed
    public virtual bool AcceptedByRequester { get; set; }
}

public UserToRequestSubscriptionMapping()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.CreatedDate);
    Map(x => x.AcceptedByRequester);
    Map(x => x.IsActive);
    Map(x => x.DeactivatedDate);
    References(x => x.Request).Column("RequestId");
    References(x => x.User).Column("UserId");
    Table("TheTable");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @HackedByChinese. The piece I was missing was that NHibernate knows the ID of the request based on the new Request property. So I have to either get, or create a Request with the appropriate ID when doing an insert for UserToRequestSubscription. I'm assuming that as long as I've got `Cascade.None()` on the reference it should be fine to give it a `Request` with just the ID.